# Importing a PNG image as a matrix of pixels

Tags: javascript, import, html5-canvas, png

I am able to get the content of a PNG file on my same server using XHR. However, I have no clue on how I should proceed to turn this "text" into an array of pixels. Is there an easy way of doing so in JavaScript? I have seen [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910520/how-to-get-image-matrix-2d-using-javascript-html5) which uses the canvas element, but I don't want to draw the image. If I could achieve the same without actually showing the image to the user (like drawing it on a canvas would) it'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using libraries, the p5js library can get easily the RGBA values of any image with the `get()` method without displaying the image:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
      <script>
        function preload(){
            image = loadImage("./myImage.png");
        }

        function setup(){
            let arr=[];
            for(let i = 0 ; i < image.width; i++){
                for(let j = 0 ; j < image.height; j++){
                    let myPixel = image.get(i,j);
                    arr.push(myPixel)
                }
            }
            console.log(arr)
        }

        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does this [codepen](https://codepen.io/morganlock/pen/eYOGZRP?editors=1111) works for you ?(turn off automatic run in settings). I think you can use your own function but you must be careful to wait till the image is completely loaded before trying to build the array containing pixel values.

Comment: It seems quite of a huge library for this purpose, something more minimal could be better. However, what is the `loadImage` function?

Comment: May be another way would be just to set your canvas with `hidden=true` property so that the canvas is not directly visible on the page. (`<canvas id="myCanvas" width="220" height="277" hidden="true">`)

Comment: Is `loadImage` from p5.js as well?

Comment: yes it is. Also p5 launch automatically `function preload()` then `function setup()`.

Comment: Can't I just use the function and ignore the automatically launched functions?

Comment: I somehow get a `ReferenceError: loadImage is not defined` despite having imported the script from cdnjs in the HTML as you did. If I try to define a `preload()` method as you do, the `image` name is not defined instead.

Comment: Just edited my answer to include a codepen for you to try.